# Differential equation and equation with parameter

Tags: differential-equations

I have the equations

```
x[t] == Exp[m t] && (2 t + 1) x''[t] + 2 (2 t - 1) x'[t] - 8 x[t] == 0
```

Please tell me which function to use to solve it and find the parameter `m` from the first equation that will solve the second,

I used `DSolve` on the second equation and found `m = -2`, but maybe there is another way.

Comment: `Simplify[DSolve[{(2 t+1)x''[t]+2(2 t-1)x'[t]-8 x[t]==0, x[0]==a, x'[0]==b}, x[t], t]]` then compare that with `x[t]==Exp[m*t]` to see what initial conditions can give you that.

Comment: thanks, but in my exercise i have to first of all find this parameter m and then solve differential equation, i though it may not like my teacher

Comment: Hummm.. That's a weird one. How about you assign `f=Exp[m*t]` without having assigned any prior value to m or t. Then you use the `D` function to find `D[f,t]` and `D[f,{t,2}]` and then you substitute all those into your `(2 t+1) x''[t]+2(2 t-1)x'[t]-8 x[t]==0` Then could you think how you might use `Solve` on that?

Comment: I dont no how to use Solve, but I used help and thought something that.... fun[t_] := Exp[m t] , Dfun = D[fun[t], t],DDfun = D[Dfun, t],form = ForAll[{t}, (2 t + 1) DDfun + 2 (2 t - 1) Dfun - 8 fun[t] == 0],Resolve[form, Reals]  thanks all of you

Comment: Interesting method you found. `Solve[(2 t+1) DDfun+2 (2 t-1) Dfun-8 fun[t]==0,m]` Then carefully check any result from MMA to make certain it is a real solution and not just a glitch.